# Wie schreibt man diese Variante von „ja“?

Tags: spelling, slang

Wie schreibt man etwas, das nach [ʝoː] klingt und ein nicht-formelles *ja* bedeutet? Ist eine der folgenden Varianten richtig?

- jo
- jeu
- jio

Comment: man buchstabiert keinen slang ;) ich persönlich würde der Liste hier aber, gegeben den Fall man buchstabierte slang diese Interpretationen hinzufügen: `jou` / `yo`

Comment: Übrigens hat „buchstabieren“ eine engere Bedeutung als „to spell“.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz eben deswegen buchstabiert man auch keinen slang ;) man versucht höchstens ihn textlich wiederzugeben ;)

Comment: Ich habe es in _schreiben_ geändert.

Comment: Carsten, I think I'll ask you to elaborate in a new question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wenn es tatsächlich [ʝoː] ist, dann *jo*. Es gibt allerdings auch [ʝɔʊ] und [ʝoɑ] mit Diphthongen, die im Deutschen normalerweise nicht vorkommen und für die es daher keine festen Konventionen gibt; ich würde sie *jou* und *joa* schreiben.

Comment: Ist eigentlich bekannt, wann und wie Yo [ʝɔʊ] in die deutsche Sprache kam? Klingt sehr nach einem englischen Ursprung. Interessanterweise ist die Verwendung von Yo in Deutschland nicht auf junge Leute begrenzt, während es in Österreich wenn überhaupt nur als Jugendsprache vorkommt.

Answer (score 5):

Falls es keine etablierte Schreibweise gibt, würde ich die bestmögliche phonetische Approximation verwenden. Im vorliegenden Fall gehe ich davon aus, daß "jo" die konventionelle Schreibweise ist.